# Custom jQuery plugin, exposing methods, and storing element information

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing my first jQuery plug-in, but I've run into a couple of problems. In my first attempt I successfully implemented the basic plug-in, but now I need to expose additional methods for the client to use.

After numerous articles, stackoverflow posts, and reading the documentation I thought I could create an object and store it in the element .data() cache. However, the code I've written seems to reference the same object when I call my plug-in.

Admittedly I'm still in the learning phases of jQuery so my terminology is lacking and google hasn't been able to pull through for me.

```
var CONST_TEST_KEY = "test-data-key";

(function($){
var TestObject = function(e, o){
    var elem = $(e);

    this.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    this.GetRandom = function() {
        alert(this.random);
    }
};

$.fn.testJQueryPlugin = function(o) {
        return $.each(function() {
            var currentElement = $(this);

            if(currentElement.data(CONST_TEST_KEY))
                return;

            currentElement.data(CONST_TEST_KEY, new TestObject(currentElement, {}));
        });
};
 })(jQuery)
```

The HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var object1 = $("#entry1").testJQueryPlugin();
        var object2 = $("#entry2").testJQueryPlugin();

        alert($(object1).data(CONST_TEST_KEY).random);
        alert($(object2).data(CONST_TEST_KEY).random);
    });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="entry1">
      x
  </div>
  <div id="entry2">
     y
  </div>
 </body>
```

This code displays two alerts both have the same value. I expected each alert to have a different value. I would appreciate any solutions, pointers, and even better an explanation why it works this way and/or why I should do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one immediate problem I see is in your call to `each()`. It looks like you're mixing up [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) (a generic iterator function) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). You're not even passing a proper first argument to `jQuery.each()`, so it's not iterating over what you think it is. Try this on for size:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xaydr/

(includes some other cleanup as well, like providing proper chaining using `return this;`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now I feel stupid, in my actual plug-in I'm using it correctly, but in my POC I missed that.

Comment: @Skyler: you're welcome. Cut-and-paste is always better than trying to retype when asking questions on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your call to [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is missing a parameter.  The first parameter is the collection over which to iterate, and the second parameter is the function to call.

It should look like this:

```
$.fn.testJQueryPlugin = function(o) {
    return $.each(this, function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);

        if(currentElement.data(CONST_TEST_KEY))
            return;

        currentElement.data(CONST_TEST_KEY, new TestObject(currentElement, {}));
    });
};
```

[see it in action at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwL3n/)

Comment: I would argue that [the other `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) is the one that should be used in this case - not the generic iterator function.